# Restore Page Layout in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, design

I have changed the page layout for Intranet site to a new layout.
However, now I need to revert.

Any suggestion on how to get the old Page layout?

Comment: Is versioning enabled? If yes then you can restore to previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Open in designer and navigate to the path and choose Reset to site definition

Comment: Well I want to change to a new Page layout and test it and if needed revert to the old page layout.

Comment: Create a page using the newly devloped page layout. After testing go to Edit properties of the page and change the page layout property to 'Page' (Default)

Comment: thanka will check n update